# CSS: have a fixed height for image header

Tags: html, css, header, height

I have a header that is styled like so:

```
header {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height:50%; 
color: #fff;
background-image: url(../images/header.jpg);
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}
```

This fills up the whole screen, how can I make it a fixed height (in pixels)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question

Like Acrux said change the height to px instead of % and also add these lines to your code :

```
header {

   overflow: hidden;

}
```

Or You could try changing the Div to a display block by adding this line :

```
header {

   display:block;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change height to px; instead of %